# Codepipeline : Read data from previous step

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I am trying to setup a test pipeline. 1st step is "Source" with gets a CF template from CodeCommit repo. Next Stage is where the template is executed in CloudFormation - Builds a ELB, AS Group and Launch Config (User-data - Installs HTTPD, Deploys custom index.html and starts HTTPD). The Outputs section will display ELB's DNS Name **(*"Value": {"Fn::GetAtt" : [ "elbTest", "DNSName" ]}*)**

Now I need to read this ELB DNS name in 3rd Stage which would be a Lambda function to validate URL health check. How do I do it? I don't want to hardcode the DNS name in User Parameters field. Is there a way my invoked Lambda function could get this value?

Answer (score 1):

Use output artifact of CloudFormation create/update action as input artifact for Lambda function. In Lambda function it will be present in event data in `inputArtifacts` array as location on s3 with zip file. That zip file will contain JSON file with Stack output (its file name can be specified in CloudFormation deploy action).

For reference you can look here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-action-reference.html

Especially "Example JSON event" in first link and `OutputFileName` in second.

Comment: Yes.. That's exactly I did. I was able to get the Bucket and KeyName in lambda. Wanted to process further ie get till the File and then it's output. Thanks. I'll try it out and update.